# PowerBI Embedded - How can I access the DOM elements inside the Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, powerbi-embedded

I have an IFrame embedded in a web application hosted on my localhost which displays a report. I want to be able to select the dom elements inside that IFrame via JQuery so that I can add some custom events, stop the propagation of click events etc. I know this breaks the same-origin policy but is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - you cannot access the elements within the Power BI iframe.  The closest you can get would be to create a custom Power BI Visual.  This will give you access to the DOM elements/events of your own visuals, but not other visuals on the page.